# How to get a slanted schwa sign in \textsuperscript size?

Tags: fonts, superscripts

There are in Tipa package two options: `\schwa` which makes slanted “schwa” of a peculiar size, and `\textschwa` which adjust to the text-size (for example when in `\textsuperscript`, it gets the right dimension), but unfortunately is not slanted. How to get a slanted schwa sign in superscript?

```
\documentclass[a4,pdftex,dev]{book}
\usepackage[noenc]{tipa}
\begin{document}
\textit{ahmiia zaoth etc}\textit{\textsuperscript{{\textschwa}}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The font is respected if you use a better syntax:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tipa}
\newcommand{\upschwa}{\textsuperscript{\textschwa}}

\begin{document}
\textit{ahmiia zaoth etc\upschwa}

ahmiia zaoth etc\upschwa

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note though that the TIPA fonts don't have italics, but only slanted.

Loading `tipa` with `noenc` would give infinite recursion, so it's better to omit the option. Also `a4` and `dev` are not options for the `book` class, you probably meant `a4paper` and `draft`; the option `pdftex` should never be specified.

Comment: I’ve copied that macro but it does not produce the same results on my machine: it displays the same superscript-size, but un-slanted schwa, in both instances.

Comment: @Julieta What TeX distribution are you running?

Comment: @ egreg It is TeX Live 2012.

Comment: @Julieta I tried also with TeX Live 2012 and get the same result.